# HTML/PHP Post method to different server

Tags: php, html, post

I want to create a POST method form that sends details to a PHP script on another server (ie, not its localhost). Is this even possible? I imagine GET is fine, so is POST possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="http://the.other.server.com/script.php">
```

Comment: thats great, but the question is: does the POST data actually get received at the external php script? Isn't post data handled locally by apache?

Comment: The data goes to whatever URL you specify in the `action`. If that's on another server entirely, it goes there and would not ever touch the server that the form was loaded from.

Comment: @rom — POST data is handled 'locally' by the server that receives the HTTP request.

Comment: It is recieved. The only probability that can cause it SEEMS it doesn't recieve: a) the name you use for values is not the same b) it checks referrer.

Comment: Something to bear in mind is that obviously you are consequently redirecting the user to that other server so he does not stay on your website.

Comment: @Ben D: outright false. POST data is sent in the message body. GET data goes "in the headers", because it's part of the requested URL.

Comment: @Marc: thanks for the clarification. That explains why POST data doesn't have the strict default length limits that GET has. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to do that on your server (i.e. you want your server to act as a proxy) you can use cURL for that.

```
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://domain.com/get-post.php';
$fields_string = "";
$fields = array(
        'lname'=>urlencode($last_name), // Assuming there was something like $_POST[last_name]
        'fname'=>urlencode($first_name)
    );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

However if you just simply want to send a POST request to another server, you can just change the `action` attribute:

```
<form action="http://some-other-server.com" method="POST">
```

Comment: I just didn't know it was possible to post across servers. I don't know how the POST method works the way it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is another question on Stack Overflow that shows a better way to url-ify the variables.  It is better because the method shown in the answer above breaks when you use nested associative arrays (aka hashes).

[How do I use arrays in cURL POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596799/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-curl-post-requests)

If you are really wanting to build that query string manually, you can. However, http_build_query will make your "url-ify the data for the POST" section unnecessary. –  Benjamin Powers Nov 28 '12 at 2:48