# How do I use arrays in cURL POST requests

Tags: php, post, curl

I am wondering how do I make this code support arrays? At the moment the `images` array only seems to send the first value.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://api.example.com/api';
$fields = array(
            'username' => "annonymous",
            'api_key' => urlencode("1234"),
            'images[]' => urlencode(base64_encode('image1')),
            'images[]' => urlencode(base64_encode('image2'))
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

and this is what is received at the api

```
VAR: username = annonymous
VAR: api_key = 1234
VAR: images = Array
array(3) { 
         ["username"]=> string(10) "annonymous" 
         ["api_key"]=> string(4) "1234" 
         ["images"]=> array(1) { // this should contain 2 strings :( what is happening?
                               [0]=> string(8) "aW1hZ2Uy" 
                               } 
         }
```

What is happening to the second value in `images[]`?

Comment: Do a `print_r($fields)` after you declare your `$fields` array and it'll become obvious why this doesn't work (hint: there's only one `images[]` key-value pair).

Comment: okay I see, so what should I be doing?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You are just creating your array incorrectly.  You could use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$fields = array(
            'username' => "annonymous",
            'api_key' => urlencode("1234"),
            'images' => array(
                 urlencode(base64_encode('image1')),
                 urlencode(base64_encode('image2'))
            )
        );
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
```

So, the entire code that you could use would be:

```
<?php
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://api.example.com/api';
$fields = array(
            'username' => "annonymous",
            'api_key' => urlencode("1234"),
            'images' => array(
                 urlencode(base64_encode('image1')),
                 urlencode(base64_encode('image2'))
            )
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: I've tried that but then it just sends `images = array`, array being a  string :/ `var_dump($_POST['images']` returns `string(5) "Array" 1`

Comment: hmm, that's strange.  Did you use the http_build_query?  If I echo the $fields_string above, it gives me username=annonymous&api_key=1234&images%5B0%5D=aW1hZ2Ux&images%5B1%5D=aW1hZ2Uy

Comment: I get `username=annonymous&api_key=1234&images=Array` no I don't think I use `http_build_query` ?

Comment: If you are really wanting to build that query string manually, you can.  However, http_build_query will make your "url-ify the data for the POST" section unnecessary.

Comment: ohhhh, I see, :P now it works with `$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);` thanks so much :D

Comment: thanks for the answerl!! I was able to form url with this but now how am i supposed to parse this url at the server(which is using cherrypy)?

Comment: extract($_POST);
is a security gap! Do not use it

Comment: I'm programming in PHP about 8 years but I see this method now. This is awesome method thank you...

Comment: to add to what jakob said, you shouldn't use extract on $_POST or $_GET without the prefix options. using them with prefix should be fine. but ofcourse do your own research, security aspects keep changing!

Answer (score -2):

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    $data = array(
        'client_id' => 'xx',
        'client_secret' => 'xx',
        'redirect_uri' => $x,
        'grant_type' => 'xxx',
        'code' => $xx,
    );

    $data = http_build_query($data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
```