# Send array as post in php

Tags: php, curl, post

Hi  I have api with the following requirement.

Send post data like that:

```
data[email]  : test@test.com
data[firstName] :first
data[lastName]  : last
data[country]   :DE
```

How can I send it via curl?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in cURL POST requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596799/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-curl-post-requests)

Answer (score -1):

See this answer: [How do I use arrays in cURL POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596799/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-curl-post-requests#13596901)

if you already have the array $data:

```
$field_string = http_build_query($data);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
...
```