# Sending complex json data on PHP POST

Tags: php, curl

I need to call a post method containing complex body data:

```
{
    "client": {
      "clientId":      "yourcompanyname",
      "clientVersion": "1.5.2"
    },
    "threatInfo": {
      "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
      "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS"],
      "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
      "threatEntries": [
        {"url": "http://www.urltocheck1.org/"},
        {"url": "http://www.urltocheck2.org/"},
        {"url": "http://www.urltocheck3.com/"}
      ]
    }
  }
```

I found different examples using `curl` and using `stream_context_create` but all examples simply use an array as body data. None had a complex json-structure as needed in my example. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you sending to the server or from the server?

Comment: TO the server. It is about the request not the response

Comment: Isn't this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl? Can't you just **json_encode** your data?

Comment: @OleAlbers  Did you actually try to follow any of the examples that you found? Or did you just assume that they wouldn't do what you wanted? If you did try, please include your attempts in your question along with the results.

Comment: My problem simply is that I do not have a simple flat Key/Value-Pair Structure as required by arrays, but hierarchical data.

Comment: @OleAlbers What you have is perfectly fine for posting as JSON.  I suggest you review some questions about posting raw JSON via curl, and take some time to make an attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl and PHP - how can I pass a json through curl by PUT,POST,GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get) also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882777/php-curl-using-post-raw-json-data)

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// not necessarily but ... 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```