# PHP cURL gives an error but works fine in POSTMAN

Tags: php, api, curl, postman

I have some problem(s) with PHP cURL. I tried to get data from the API using PHP cURL. This is my cURL code in PHP :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.example.com/dos/AW/API",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"Filter\" : {\"IsActive\" : \"True\",\"OutputSelector\" : \"Name\"}}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "API_ACTION: GetItem",
    "API_KEY: MHlIARzQqxVpOg2dUxH4q9w7bx3pOL6K",
    "Accept: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

?>
```

With that code I can get a response but the response contains some errors. I also tried using `POSTMAN` to check, and the API works fine as I got a successful response with the same data. My question is: "Is there anything wrong with my `cURL` code that would explain why I got an error when I used `cURL` and I got successful response in `POSTMAN` "?

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596799/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-curl-post-requests and check your CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is a string like field1=value&field2=value2 etc. Then I think your are missing curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1), to do a POST.

Comment: What do you receive response code ? Or what error?

Comment: @BenRoob Maybe you can give some example ?

Comment: @BartoszKowalczyk I just got Error Messages in response

Comment: @Antonio Please, Tell us which error message ;)

Comment: @BenRoob Just like this `{"CurrentTime":"2017-07-21 09:05:25","xmlns:ns":"API","Ack":"Error"}`

Comment: @BenRoob I know exactly that is on request body because the docs say that.

Comment: Sorry, my comment before was shit!! Json goes to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: @BenRoob So, what is I must do now ?

Comment: Hard to say, I do not know the api your posting to. First, add curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1) to your code.

Comment: @BenRoob I already add `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1)` but I still got error

Comment: My last idea: data you are posting is invalid (e.g. header, authentication...). You could also send an http header for user agent (which postman does?). Compare the postman request to curl request. Sorry.

Comment: @BenRoob I got that cURL code from POSTMAN. I generate the code via that. Do you ever used postman before ?

Comment: I use it regularly, also Restlet Client for Chrome. But that's off-topic ;)

Comment: I added following code, my curl is working now: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

given that you aren't showing us the successful postman request, we can't know for sure what errors you make, that said, you are making a couple of obvious mistakes here.

first off, when debugging curl code, use `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` , it gies you a lot of useful information when debugging your curl requests (and if you did this, you would probably notice how the Postman requests's `content-type` is completely different from curl's `content-type`  http headers - more on this soon)

second, when you want a POST request, don't use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, use `CURLOPT_POST`.

third, when passing a string to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, the content-type implicitly becomes `Content-Type: application/x-www-urlencoded`, unless you override it. and you are obviously NOT sending x-www-urlencoded data, but JSON-encoded data, so your content-type is all wrong, its supposed to be `Content-type: application/json`

fourth, you can hardcode the json if you want, but the code looks much prettier if you json_encode it

fifth, don't use setopt / setopt_array without checking the return type.

fixing all that, you'll end up with something like:

```
function ecurl_setopt_array($ch, array $options) {
    if (! curl_setopt_array ( $ch, $options )) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt_array failed. ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ': ' . curl_error ( $ch ) );
    }
}

$curl = curl_init ();

ecurl_setopt_array ( $curl, array (
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.example.com/dos/AW/API",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode ( array (
                'Filter' => array (
                        'IsActive' => 'True',
                        'OutputSelector' => 'Name' 
                ) 
        ) ),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                "API_ACTION: GetItem",
                "API_KEY: MHlIARzQqxVpOg2dUxH4q9w7bx3pOL6K",
                "Accept: application/json",
                'Content-Type: application/json' 
        ) 
) );

$response = curl_exec ( $curl );
$err = curl_error ( $curl );

curl_close ( $curl );

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Edit: fixed the json data, when i wrote it, i didn't see that `isActive` is not an actual boolean, but the string literal `True` - i mistakenly encoded it as a json boolean true instead, sorry, fixed. (although i suspect it's supposed to be a boolean anyway, and that your original code just encodes it wrong, perhaps you should double check `isActive`'s type in the api docs, assuming there is one)

Comment: I got what is wrong. Replace `ecurl_setopt_array` with `curl_setopt_array` and it will works.

Comment: Is there a practical reason to use `CURLOPT_POST` instead of `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` for POST or is it purely semantic? I've used the latter quite a bit without issue.

Comment: @MagnusBull yes there is. quoting [the official libcurl documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html): ```Many people have wrongly used this option to replace the entire request with their own, including multiple headers and POST contents. While that might work in many cases, it will cause libcurl to send invalid requests and it could possibly confuse the remote server badly. Use CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to set POST data. Use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to replace or extend the set of headers sent by libcurl. Use CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION to change HTTP version.```, hmmm

Comment: @MagnusBull what i have noticed personally is that CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST overrides everything else, and it's sticky; when you use CUSTOMREQUEST, `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` and `CURLOPT_PUT` and `CURLOPT_POST` no longer work properly, as CUSTOMREQUEST overrides all of them.. anyway the official libcurl documentation say "dont use CUSTOMREQUEST for POST requests, it could cause curl to send a malformed request", that should be reason enough.

Answer (score 1):

@Antonio, Response you are getting is from the other end, might be you are missing something which restrict the processing of query at other end. try to print http_code, or use curl_getinfo to get complete information.

in case of response code is 200, then you may ask from another end to validate the request.

PS: not able to comment because of repo restrictions.

Comment: use the following line in your code below the line of response 
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

Comment: use `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` - it gives more information than all of curl_getinfo 's options combined.