# Is there a way to handle large arrays of colums from MySQL when importing via $POST

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to work on a API to import data to MySQL Database. 
I have it working on a small scale.

I have now altered it so its more in line with the current database. Its a large table and been poorly structured, But for simplicity and maintaining am trying to keep MySQL database and the Applications database inline.
MSQL = Windows based application: 
MySQL = The Server database, Am extracting Data out of MSQL hosted locally and importing it to a MySQL Database hosted externally.

As i have expanded the code, its no longer working, this could be a number of factors like the table needs structuring / indexing / primary, or i am passing too much data via a query. The application is starting to look very messy.

The question is, is it necessary and better practice me listing out each column and matching up the data sets apposed to trying to utilize the `MySQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to list the columns instead.

Here is the code so far, I have already removed a number of columns.

We have a Server and Host:

**Server Code**

Class file: `Api.php`

```
class API
{
    private $connect = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->database_connection();
    }

    function database_connection()
    {
       $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$Host;dbname=$DatabaseName", $DatabaseUsername, $DatabasePassword);
    }
function insert()    // Insert Function 
    {
        if(isset($_POST["Branch"]))
        {
            $form_data = array(
                ':Branch'=>$_POST['Branch'],
                ':Date'=>$_POST['Date'],
                ':Week'=>$_POST['Week'],
                ':Period'=>$_POST['Period'],
                ':Invoice_No'=>$_POST['Invoice_No'],
                ':Invoice_Reference'=>$_POST['Invoice_Reference'],
                ':Line_No'=>$_POST['Line_No'],
                ':Till_No'=>$_POST['Till_No'],
                ':Operator'=>$_POST['Operator'],
                ':Stock_Code'=>$_POST['Stock_Code'],
                ':Barcode'=>$_POST['Barcode'],
                ':Line_Quantity'=>$_POST['Line_Quantity'],
                ':Weight'=>$_POST['Weight'],
                ':Weight_Unit'=>$_POST['Weight_Unit'],
                ':Man_Weighed'=>$_POST['Man_Weighed'],
                ':Unit_ID'=>$_POST['Unit_ID'],
                ':Line_Price_Band'=>$_POST['Line_Price_Band'],
                ':Original_Sell'=>$_POST['Original_Sell'],
                ':Actual_Sell'=>$_POST['Actual_Sell'],
                ':Cost'=>$_POST['Cost'],
                ':Vat_Rate'=>$_POST['Vat_Rate'],
                ':Discount_Rate'=>$_POST['Discount_Rate'],
                ':Value_Goods'=>$_POST['Value_Goods'],
                ':Value_VAT'=>$_POST['Value_VAT'],
                ':Value_Sale'=>$_POST['Value_Sale'],
                ':Value_Cost'=>$_POST['Value_Cost'],
                ':Price_Override_Amount'=>$_POST['Price_Override_Amount'],
                ':Price_Overrided'=>$_POST['Price_Overrided'],
                ':Discounted'=>$_POST['Discounted'],
                ':Account_No'=>$_POST['Account_No'],
                ':Sub_Account_No'=>$_POST['Sub_Account_No'],
                ':Customer_Account'=>$_POST['Customer_Account'],
                ':Sub_Customer_Account'=>$_POST['Sub_Customer_Account'],
                ':Cust_Type_ID'=>$_POST['Cust_Type_ID'],
                ':Super_Department_ID'=>$_POST['Super_Department_ID'],
                ':Department_ID'=>$_POST['Department_ID'],
                ':Group_ID'=>$_POST['Group_ID'],
                ':Sub_Group_ID'=>$_POST['Sub_Group_ID'],
                ':Retail_Location_ID'=>$_POST['Retail_Location_ID'],
                ':Retail_Sub_Location_ID'=>$_POST['Retail_Sub_Location_ID'],
                ':Entry_Method'=>$_POST['Entry_Method'],
                ':End_Sale_Discount_Rate'=>$_POST['End_Sale_Discount_Rate'],
                ':Loyalty_Discount_Rate'=>$_POST['Loyalty_Discount_Rate'],
                ':Date_Time_Stamp'=>$_POST['Date_Time_Stamp']

            );
            $query = "
            INSERT INTO Lines 
            (Branch, Date, Week, Period, Invoice_No, Invoice_Reference, Line_No, Till_No, Operator, Stock_Code, Barcode, Line_Quantity, Weight, Weight_Unit, Man_Weighed, Unit_ID, Line_Price_Band, Original_Sell, Actual_Sell, Cost, Vat_Rate, Discount_Rate, Value_Goods, Value_VAT, Value_Sale, Value_Cost, Price_Override_Amount, Price_Overrided, Discounted, Account_No, Sub_Account_No, Customer_Account, Sub_Customer_Account, Cust_Type_ID, Super_Department_ID, Department_ID, Group_ID, Sub_Group_ID, Retail_Location_ID, Retail_Sub_Location_ID, Entry_Method, End_Sale_Discount_Rate, Loyalty_Discount_Rate, Date_Time_Stamp) VALUES 
            (:Branch, :Date, :Week, :Period, :Invoice_No, :Invoice_Reference, :Line_No, :Till_No, :Operator, :Stock_Code, :Barcode, :Line_Quantity, :Weight, :Weight_Unit, :Man_Weighed, :Unit_ID, :Line_Price_Band, :Original_Sell, :Actual_Sell, :Cost, :Vat_Rate, :Discount_Rate, :Value_Goods, :Value_VAT, :Value_Sale, :Value_Cost, :Price_Override_Amount, :Price_Overrided, :Discounted, :Account_No, :Sub_Account_No, :Customer_Account, :Sub_Customer_Account, :Cust_Type_ID, :Super_Department_ID, :Department_ID, :Group_ID, :Sub_Group_ID, :Retail_Location_ID, :Retail_Sub_Location_ID, :Entry_Method, :End_Sale_Discount_Rate, :Loyalty_Discount_Rate, :Date_Time_Stamp)
            ";
            $statement = $this->connect->prepare($query);
            if($statement->execute($form_data))
            {
                echo $statement ;
                $data[] = array(
                    'success'   =>  '1'
                );
            }
            else
            {
                var_dump($statement) ;
                $data[] = array(
                    'success'   =>  '0'
                );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $data[] = array(
                'success'   =>  '0'
            );
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Calling the Function: Handler `test_api.php`
// This does have an include for Api.php

```
if($_GET["action"] == 'insert')
{
    $data = $api_object->insert();
}
```

**Host code**

This wont be the final thing, as ill be extracting from MSQL building the array and posting this way, This is just laid out like so for testing

```
<?php

$form_data = array(
    'Branch' => '1',
    'Date' => '8/11/2018 13:42:00',
    'Week' => '1',
    'Period' => '1',
    'Invoice_No' => '9999998',
    'Invoice_Reference' => '99999998',
    'Line_No' => '1',
    'Till_No' => '1',
    'Operator' => '99',
    'Stock_Code' => '123456',
    'Barcode' => '654321',
    'Line_Quantity' => '99',
    'Weight' => '',
    'Weight_Unit' => '',
    'Man_Weighed' => '',
    'Unit_ID' => '',
    'Line_Price_Band' => '1',
    'Original_Sell' => '99.99',
    'Actual_Sell' => '99.99',
    'Cost' => '9.99',
    'Vat_Rate' => '1',
    'Discount_Rate' => '',
    'Value_Goods' => '',
    'Value_VAT' => '',
    'Value_Sale' => '',
    'Value_Cost' => '',
    'Price_Override_Amount' => '',
    'Price_Overrided' => '',
    'Discounted' => '',
    'Account_No' => '',
    'Sub_Account_No' => '',
    'Customer_Account' => '',
    'Sub_Customer_Account' => '',
    'Cust_Type_ID' => '',
    'Super_Department_ID' => '',
    'Department_ID' => '',
    'Group_ID' => '',
    'Sub_Group_ID' => '',
    'Retail_Location_ID' => '',
    'Retail_Sub_Location_ID' => '',
    'Entry_Method' => '',
    'End_Sale_Discount_Rate' => '',
    'Loyalty_Discount_Rate' => '',
    'Date_Time_Stamp' => ''

);
$api_url = "localhost/Modules/API/Server/test_api.php?action=insert";  //change this url as per your folder path for api folder
$client = curl_init($api_url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form_data);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($client);
//     var_dump($response);
curl_close($client);

$result = json_decode($response, true);
echo $response ;
foreach($result as $keys => $values)
{
    if($result[$keys]['success'] == '1')
    {
        echo 'update';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'error';
        echo $response ;
    }
}
```

At the moment its not working, I am not sure why, As it was working fine with a much smaller dataset. 
And my IDE hasnt reported of any errors or typos, But thats something else, if you do spot a error, please do say.

The question is, is there a better way to work with large number of columns.

In previous API's i have basically just dumped the data to txt and imported from a deliminator. So this is all very new to me.

Comment: AFAIK Curl doesn't support posting arrays - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596799/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-curl-post-requests

Comment: It looks like you are sending one row per request. That is very costly. I would recommend to send multiple rows per request (e.g. 200). Also I would look into sending the data as JSON Body, instead of using classic form post.

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but is there any reason why you do not import the SQLs directly or via the mysql import tools?

Comment: Control, The end product would go down to around 100 clients. I didn't want to have to have Cron Jobs or files floating around and being processed, Importing directly would have to open up remote connections on any IP address. In previous experience with uploading files and internet drop outs corrupted files, lock key. i thought this process would remove a ton of issues i have had previously.