# What is wrong with this CURL call in PHP?

Tags: php, php-curl

```
            $POSTFIELDS = array(
                    'email' => "fodil@usa.com",
                    'phone' => "656565465422",      
        );  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents("php://input") . "&" . $POSTFIELDS);
```

I can't figure what is wrong with this, it doesn't work, I tried many things but can't make it work...

Comment: What you trying to do?

Comment: For one, it looks like you're concatenating a string with an array at the end there - that's a no-no. Search for examples on http_build_query, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596799/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-curl-post-requests

Comment: i need just integrate file_get_contents("php://input") with $POSTFIELDS on the same CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Answer (score 1):

You are passing post fields in a wrong way to the curl.
If you are receiving JSON post the use this..

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

else use normal post array $_POST.

```
$post = $_POST
```

then you CURL request will be...

```
$post['email'] = 'fodil@usa.com';
$post['phone'] = '656565465422';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: is not working bro

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: $post['email'] = 'fodil@usa.com';              and                  $_POST  = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));                  $post = $_POST  like this  the $post is work normaly and $_POST not work vice versa

Comment: $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); this is wrong check what i have posted in my answer.