# how to pass an array of data to a website's controller method without using html form?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, paypal

I have two websites developed with codeigniter.
Users can do shopping and add items to cart in website1.

When they press the 'Pay with PayPal' button, the form will be submitted to webite1's controller.
From that controller's method, I want to do some validation and send an array of data to website2's controller and make the payment from there (i.e website1's controller method).

All the libraries needed for PayPal are in website2.

How do I pass the array of data without using html forms from one website to another?

Comment: Use php curl to make a http request from website 1 to website 2 with post data

Comment: So I need to use php curl. I think It will do what I want. Thanks
 I just need to pass the data directly from php without using html form.

Comment: Fixed some spelling and formatting

Comment: Check out the second answer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065765/html-php-post-method-to-different-server This may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **curl** function in php
[(http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)