# How to pass PHP array to NodeJS HTTP server?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, curl

So I have a PHP file called "dbEmails.php", it basically writes all existing emails from MySQL to an array:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '../db.php';

$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT email FROM users');

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $emails[] = $row['email'];
}

echo json_encode(array($emails));
```

I have a NodeJS HTTP server that is used for validating whether email is already registered or not, while in registration page. Here it is:

```
var http        = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

//var emails = array called "emails" from "dbEmails.php"

function accountExists (email) {
  return emails.indexOf(email) > -1;
}

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var params = req.url.split('?')[1];
  var data   = querystring.parse(params);
  var email  = data.email;

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

  if (accountExists(email)) {
    res.write('""');
  } else {
    res.write('"true"');
  }

  res.end();
});
server.listen(6666);
```

As you can see in the code I have already commented what exactly my question is. I need to get `$emails` array from PHP into `var emails` of JS.

I searched some but couldn't find a solution. I think I'm not supposed to use AJAX, I don't know much of anything about Node at all.

What would be the best way of going about this?

**Question 2:**

Will `var emails` update automatically when there is new email entry in my database? I guess not. If it doesn't update then can someone please tell me how I should go about keeping my `var emails` up to date?

Comment: You should be able to find several examples how to use curl to send data to an http server, for example [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9065892/5781248) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From question 1,

- please update your nodejs app using express.js, good tutorial >> https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters
- your node app should accept post method
- you can call node from php using curl command and pass email data to it and get result whether success or not

From question 2,

- if you update yiue node app from my suggestion above, it should be updated automatically